# How to run a shed from a generator with no utility power?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, generator, workshop

I want to wire an off-grid shed with a bonded neutral Duromax XP9000iH generator. There won’t be much demand, but I want to make sure I do it right. I'm going to need around 10 standard 15A outlets, 1 switched lighting circuit for inside lighting and one 20A/240 outlet for window unit AC.

What is the best way to put this together? I'm thinking something like a Square D subpanel with ground bus and bar added, inlet box feeding panel via generator and then wire the shed like normal?  I've never used a generator as sole power source so I will gladly welcome any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **inlet**, an extension cord, and a panel. If less than 6 breakers could be just a subpanel, but a small-ish main panel will provide a handy disconnect switch that happens to be labeled as main breaker at some amperage that will never trip, because your generator's own breaker will trip first. But still works well for a disconnect switch. And quite ofen a 100-125A main panel "kit" with a few breakers tossed in will cost less than a subpanel they don't sell nearly as many of. Just remove (and save) the bonding screw if the generator is bonded. Yes, you'll want a ground bar kit as well for a main panel. A subpanel should already have separate ground and neutral bars, unless it showed up through a time warp from long ago.

I will comment that your window unit might be a bit outdated and inefficient - my 12K minisplits only use a bit less than 10A maximum on 240VAC. Much less most of the time. Running a generator, you probably don't want a clunker AC that defines your load by its lackadaisical efficiency. That adds up to a lot of wasted fuel, and that costs serious money, even if the AC is "but I already own this one for free!"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!  I going to take your advice and go with a main panel. I forgot to mention the AC also had a heat pump which will help us heat the shed during the winter. I live in the desert in AZ and the daytime lows will be in the 50’s so this combo until should serve us well. Thanks again for your help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The basic plan sounds fine. The key difference between a main panel and a subpanel is that a main panel has a main breaker and the neutral/ground bonded together but a subpanel doesn't have to have a main breaker and must have neutral and ground separated. You can actually use either type of panel as they can be switched around (remove bond from main panel, add main breaker to a subpanel, etc.)

The inlet, keeping the neutral/ground bond in the generator (and not in the panel), etc. all sounds good to me. As far as I know, code wants that bond in one place and without utility power it doesn't matter where (generator or panel), but I could be wrong on that.

A few things to keep in mind:

- You should have (don't know if absolutely required in this case) a disconnect switch on the panel. Yes, you could just pull the cable out of the inlet, but there are reasons/times where it may make sense to have a disconnect. (Required normally with utility power, I just don't know if it is *required* here or not.) But if you use a main panel then the main breaker functions as a disconnect.
- You need to protect the wires against overload. The generator manual is not clear what size the breaker is. If it is a 30A breaker then you can use 10 AWG wire. If it is a larger breaker then you will need to use larger wire.
- You will need ground rods...somewhere. The generator manual actually includes this. Normally it would be attached to the panel, but if the generator is essentially permanent then connecting it to the generator makes sense.
- You will need GFCI on each circuit. The generator has GFCI on the 120V receptacles but not on the 30A 240V receptacle, which is the one you'll be using. You can install GFCI/breakers in the panel or, for the 120V circuits install at the first receptacle or a dead-front (GFCI "only") for the lighting circuit.
- A decent size main panel may actually make sense, even though you only need around 5 or 6 breaker spaces. That's because a main panel will often include a main breaker (use that as a disconnect) and some "bonus breakers". In any case, get a panel where when you are all done with your *current* plans you will have at least a half dozen spaces empty so that if you later add more circuits you won't have a problem. Even though your generator has limited power capacity, lots of smaller circuits can make more sense than a few large circuits, particularly to avoid a GFCI trip or other problem on one circuit from shutting down everything else.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback!  I haven’t taken the generator out of the box yet, but you’re right there is a connection for the ground. That will make it super easy!  I will still measure ground to make sure I’m under 25ohms and if not then add another ground rod at the shed.